# PHP error, if-statement

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

Whats wring with this code?

```
if(isset($this->session->flashdata('login_error'))) {      // Line 39
     echo "You entered an incorrect email or password!";
}
```

I use Codeigniter and session is loaded in `autoload.php`.

The error message I get is:

> Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/application/views/login_view.php on line 39

Comment: try passing the flshdata as a variable form the controller, and only checking if it is set in the view. it is a best practice to separate as much of the actual data from the view

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it sounds better to do as you say.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`isset` is only necessary if you're trying to work with **variables** that may not exist. In your case you're calling a **function**, which certainly exists. Hence you don't need and in fact can't use `isset` here. Just use `if ($this->session->flashdata('login_error'))` if you want to test whether the value is *truthy*.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I follow this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEVs5JhagOE&feature=player_profilepage#t=869s , he use isset and it works for him. why?

Comment: @Loka Sorry, I'm not going to follow 15mins of jumpy video to answer that. ;) The fact is, it shouldn't work.

Comment: i understand, but thanks anyway. your code solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

just checking if($this->session->flashdata('login_error')) will return false if the result of this function is a boolean FALSE or NULL

Comment: Although just checking if($this->session->flashdata('login_error')) will return false if the result of this function is  a boolean false of null. This is probably better code.

Comment: Nonsense, just test the return value directly for truthyness.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel - There is none

Comment: @Adam why to post an answer that makes no sense? Aren't you under impression that answer should be strictly literal, even if being a nonsense that way?

Comment: With "this" in "this is probably better code", do you mean your answer or your comment? That's not clear. You should edit your answer to clarify. Currently, unless `flashdata()` returns `null`, the `if` check will always be `true`, which is probably not what's intended and hence nonsense. You could get the same effect with `if (flashdata() === null)`.

Comment: Sure, FALSE or NULL... or 0, or "", or any number of _falsy_ values.

Answer (score 1):

You can´t use a function with `isset` like that. What you could do is something like:

```
$txt = $this->session->flashdata('login_error');
if(!empty($txt))
{
     echo "You entered an incorrect email or password!";
}
```

Comment: Can be perfectly shortened to `$txt = flashdata(…); if ($txt)`. `empty` and `isset` are only necessary if the variable *may not be set*. You're setting it very explicitly on the previous line though, so it's unnecessary to test. Hence you can shorten this further to `if (flashdata(…))` for the same effect.

Comment: @deceze Although your second comment is right, I tend to feed boolean expressions to `if` statements to keep things clear but that´s just a personal preference. About the first comment, that could be but I don´t know Codeigniter that well.

Comment: That's not a CodeIgniter thing, it's simple PHP. :) I prefer to not temporarily assign to variables when there's no need, the value will be (evaluated as) boolean either way.

Comment: @deceze By the way, I´m assuming the function returns a string. If it returns `true` or `false` I would definitely put it directly in the `if` statement...

Comment: It doesn't actually matter what the function returns, the return value and hence the result of the comparison/evaluation will not change by assigning it to a variable.

Comment: @deceze I was actually refering to your statement that `$this->session->flashdata('login_error')` is equal to `flashdata('login_error')` being Codeigniter specific but seeing your own answer I guess that´s not what you meant. I took your `shortening` comment a bit too literally...

Answer (score 1):

`isset` only checks if a variable in instantiated. Since you can only return instantiated variables, `isset` is invalid there. Your best bet would be to do it like:

```
if($this->session->flashdata('login_error') != null) {      // Line 39
     echo "You entered an incorrect email or password!";
}
```

Comment: The argument to `isset` is not evaluated (this is why you don't get a Notice if the variable doesn't exist); thus the function return value has nothing to do with it. You're trying to determine whether the function itself exists, which is invalid with `isset`.